# Routing issue in Global file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

Routes Information

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        // Parameter defaults
            );

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default1", // Route name
        "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Url Information

```
http://localhost:24060/home/22323      //Failed
http://localhost:24060/home/index/22323    //Passed\
```

Query, How can i pass both url ?

Comment: Swap them around. Routes are evaluated top-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the default route last. Also you should create a constraint in the other route  to not to block the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default1",
        "{controller}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = @"\d+" });
        //second segment has to be an integer, otherwise skip this route.

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```